# Excel find and replace value macro or vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

this is sample data from my csv file , I have many cells in column A similar to this.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jeu8XB6LgAc1UXuepDtXT4vdjTEhP0Ts/view?usp=sharing

In the Find and Replace box, with the option "look in value" selected ,I am able to find all abc , then select all found values, then click replace tab, then click replace. but doesn't work when click replace all.

how can I let the Replace All work for that sample file, or is there a macro that can do the job for the data in the sample file?

I have googled excel forum and other sites, but they don't seem to have a solution.

any help is appreciated

Comment: FYI, you've got an `img.abccom` in there.

Comment: I copied and pasted the cell into word and got 7 results.In xl I used find/replace abc replace with zzz and it replaced all 7

Comment: it would be the best if the find and replace can be done on excel, I have many excel files like this.

Comment: @Davesexel  did you replace in excel with the replace all button ?

Comment: You asked this question earlier, but used a different user account!!!

Comment: Duplicate here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51576327/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that should work

```
Sub replace_abc()

    Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LstRw)
    rng.Value = Replace(rng, "abc", "zzz")

End Sub
```

Comment: This question is the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576327/excel-find-and-replace-look-in-values) as per DavesExcel and Solar Mike had mentioned above.